# Hide other windows of the same app in Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way for me to hide other windows of the same app in Mac?  I know of the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> shortcut key to hide all other windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide some of the windows in one application, minimise them. To minimise all windows in an application, hold the option key and press the minimise button.

The basic model: hiding applies to apps, minimising to windows.

Comment: This doesn't leave just a single app window left. As I understood it, the OP wants to minimise all but the active window of an application. I don't know of a way to do that, though I suspect an applescript could be rustled up to do it...

Comment: Accepted answer, because I interpreted as 'no shortcut key available'